# Templated operator<< isn't being recognized

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, operators, stringstream

I created a class called SkipToChar that's supposed to be able to be used as follows:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "Hello," << SkipToChar(7) << "world!" << std::endl;
```

Which would print "Hello, world!" (notice the space.) Basically it's supposed to skip to the character at the specified index using spaces. But apparently the compiler doesn't recognize the `operator<<` I created for it. Interestingly, calling `operator<<` explicitly, even without giving any template parameters (like `operator<<(oss, SkipToChar(7));` works fine; it just doesn't work if I actual

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

template <typename _Elem>
struct basic_SkipToChar
{
    typename std::basic_string<_Elem>::size_type pos;
    basic_SkipToChar(typename std::basic_string<_Elem>::size_type position)
    {
        pos = position;
    }
};

template <typename _Elem>
inline std::basic_ostringstream<_Elem> &operator<<(std::basic_ostringstream<_Elem> &oss, const basic_SkipToChar<_Elem> &skip)
{
    typename std::basic_string<_Elem>::size_type length = oss.str().length();
    for (typename std::basic_string<_Elem>::size_type i = length; i < skip.pos; i++) {
        oss << (_Elem)' ';
    }
    return oss;
}

typedef basic_SkipToChar<char> SkipToChar;
typedef basic_SkipToChar<wchar_t> WSkipToChar;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    /*ERROR*/ oss << "Hello," << SkipToChar(8) << "world!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << oss.str();
    return 0;
}
```

It gives me the following error when I try to compile it:

```
error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'basic_SkipToChar<char>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

I marked the line the error is on with a comment. What's going wrong here?

Comment: best only overload `operator<<(std::ostream&, whatever)`, since `std::ostream&` is what these operators usually return and hence what you get when concatinating calls, as in `out << a << b << c;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jarod42 points out, the return type of *all* of the built-in
`operator<<` is `std::ostream&`.  This is a basic principle of
how streams operator; except for the actual sink or source, the
stream should be indifferent as to where the data is going to or
coming from.

It's possible to provide manipulators which only work for one
type of stream, or do different things for different types of
streams, by using a `dynamic_cast` in the manipulator:

```
std::ostream&
operator<<( std::ostream& dest, SkipToChar const& manip )
{
    std::ostringstream* d = dynamic_cast<std::ostringstream*>( &dest );
    if ( d != nullptr ) {
        //  ...
    }
    return dest;
}
```

In general, however, this is a very bad idea; clients will be
very surprised that outputting to a string results in different
text than outputting to a file.

What you seem to be trying to do is to more or less emulate
a form of tabbing.  The best way to do this is to use
a filtering output streambuf, which keeps track of where you are
in the line, and can be inserted between the `std::ostream` and
the actual sink regardless of the type of stream:

```
class TabbingOutputStreambuf : public std::streambuf
{
    std::streambuf* myDest;
    std::ostream*   myOwner;
    int             myInLineCount;
public:
    TabbingOutputStreambuf( std::streambuf* dest )
        : myDest( dest )
        , myOwner( nullptr )
        , myInLineCount( 0 )
    {
    }
    TabbingOutputStreambuf( std::ostream& dest )
        : myDest( dest.rdbuf() )
        , myOwner( &dest )
        , myInLineCount( 0 )
    {
        myOwner.rdbuf( this );
    }
    ~TabbingOutputStreambuf()
    {
        if ( myOwner != nullptr ) {
            myOwner->rdbuf( myDest );
        }
    }

    int overflow( int ch ) override
    {
        if ( ch == '\n' ) {
            myInLineCount = 0;
        } else {
            ++ myInLineCount;
        }
        return myDest->sputc( ch );
    }

    //      Special function...
    int tabTo( int n )
    {
        int retval = 0;
        while ( retval == 0 && myInLineCount < n ) {
            if ( overflow( ' ' ) == EOF ) {
                retval = EOF;
            }
        }
        return retval;
    }
};
```

Your manipulator would then be:

```
std::ostream&
operator<<( std::ostream& dest, SkipToChar const& manip )
{
    TabbingOutputStreambuf* sb = dynamic_cast<TabbingOutputStreambuf*>( dest.rdbuf() );
    assert( sb != nullptr );
    try {
        if ( sb->tabTo( manip.pos ) == EOF ) {
            dest.setstate( std::badbit );
        }
    } catch ( ... ) {
        dest.setstate( std::badbit );
    }
    return dest;
}
```

This is still not ideal, since it will fail with an unprotected
buffer, but you'd only use the manipulator in a context like:

```
void
generateOutput( std::ostream& dest )
{
    TabbingOutputStreambuf tabber( dest );
    dest << "Hello, " << SkipToChar( 7 ) << "world!";
    //  ...
}
```

And this will work regardless of the type of stream passed to
the function (including custom ostream classes that you don't
even know about).

EDIT:

One last point: don't bother with making things templates until you've got the basic version working.  (For what it's worth, your code doesn't work correctly for wchar_t streams anyway.  To output a space in them, you need to get the embedded locale, get the `ctype` facet from it, and use its `widen` member function.)

Comment: Thanks! I went with a simpler approach that only works with the string streams though; that's all I needed it for.

Comment: @flarn2006 If the manipulator has limited visibility, fine.  It's _generally_ a bad idea, because _clients_ will be surprised; if it's done in a context where there can be no clients, then this general rule doesn't apply.

Answer (score 5):

`oss << "Hello,"` returns `std::basic_ostream<char>` (it *loses* the string part).
So your method doesn't match (expect `std::basic_ostringstream` but got `std::basic_ostream<char>`).